# Lipschitz boundaries vs $C^1$ boundaries

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In my lecture notes I have most  theorems about Sobolev spaces stated with Lipschitz boundaries, for instance

[image]

On the  othe hand, the same theorems in Evans' PDE book are stated with $C^1$ boundaries. In fact, looks like Evans does not use Lipschitz boundaries at all as there is not even a definition of it.

**So I wonder, does one imply the other?** My guess is that $C^1$ boundaries are Lipschitz (and therefore Evans theorems are more general ?) because I found out on a quick google search that $C^1$ functions are Lipschitz, and the definitions of $C^1$ and Lipschitz boundaries involve a mapping of the same type respectively.

However  the  definition of Lipschitz boundary that I have coincides with wikipedia's definition of weakly Lipschitz boundary (I found that also surprising)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_domain#Generalization

[image]
seems a lot more complicated than that of $C^1$ boundary

[image]

, so I doubt the prove goes along the lines of just observing that $C^1$ functions are Lipschitz, as I initially thought before seeing the definitions. What do you think? Could you prove it (that $C^1$ boundaries are  weakly Lipschitz I mean, using the definitions above )or tell me where to find a proof?

Comment: $C^1$ boundaries are Lipschitz, yes. But that means the version of the theorems stated in Evans’ PDE book is weaker! He assumes more but proves the same conclusion. Anyway, there’s another book by Evans and Gariepy: *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* where you can find more refined results (about functions and sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$ in general). But here as well, you should note that they’re not fully general for example, sometimes boundedness is assumed when it’s not needed. For a more in depth Sobolev space book (in Euclidean spaces), there’s the classic by Adams.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for the suggested literature!

Comment: @peek-a-boo Can I also find the proof of "C1 boundaries are Lipschitz" in those books?

Comment: A $C^1$ function is locally Lipschitz; this is obvious from the basic mean-value theorem/inequality of differential calculus. Now the regularity of a boundary is a local property (near each point the boundary is a graph of a ___ type of function). So it immediately follows that a $C^1$ boundary is Lipschitz (atleast in the sense Evans defines it).

Comment: @peek-a-boo That is what I thought, but as stated in my post the definitions are not like I can just cut the word "$C^1$" and paste "Lipschitz" in its place. The Lipschitz definition has more details I think like the third and fouth bullets in wikipedia's definition picture above that is not present in the $C^1$ boundary definition

Comment: $C^1$ boundary in the sense of Evans implies (by what I said above) Lipschitz boundary in the sense of Evans Gariepy, which apart from notation is what Wikipedia calls strongly Lipschitz. So now your question really just becomes why strongly Lipschitz implies weakly Lipschitz. This seems to be an exercise is unwinding definitions, and choosing small enough open sets.

Comment: $C^1$ implies Lipschitz.  Lipschitz functions are a.e. differentiable. Also coordinate transformation under integral works with Lipschitz. So many results that seem to require $C^1$ are true for Lipschitz. However proofs are more technical. I think this is why in the Evans Pde book $C^1$ is used, as it is easier to learn.

Answer (score 1):

In $C^k$ boundary definition if we use $$l_p(y_1,...,y_n) = \frac{1}{r}\left(\left(y_1,...,y_{n-1},\frac{r(y_n-\gamma(y_1,...,y_{n-1}))}{\sup_y (y_n-\gamma(y_1,...,y_{n-1}))}\right)-(p_1,...,p_{n-1},0)\right)$$ then
$$l_p(\partial \Omega \cap B_r(p)) = \{y:B_1(0): y_n = 0\}$$
$$l_p(\Omega \cap B_r(p)) = \{y:B_1(0): y_n > 0\}$$

Hence $\Omega$ is weakly lipschitz if $\gamma$ is $C^1$.